# Xml Parsing - Unique Error Situation

Tags: c#, java, xml-parsing

I was trying to parse an XMLfile created using Visual Studio using a tool which uses Xerces parser and I got "content not allowed in prolog" error.

Now when I create an XML file using some other editor like notepad++ and have the exact same content as the one created above I don't get this error.

What do you think might be the problem. You might understand that this is not a repeat question.

**EDIT**
So i found out the problem. Its because the tool which i use could not handle the Bom at the beginning of the file

Comment: Are you able to post the file online?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<main>
 <node key="temp1" value="some value"/>
 <node key="temp2" value="some value"/>
 <node key="temp3" value="some value"/>
</main>
This is the file.

Comment: No, you need to post the file itself. Otherwise we're losing encoding information etc.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?pfcvs7dhzmp511f

Comment: @JonSkeet so u got somethng now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file starts with a UTF-8 [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The [XML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charencoding) say that documents may start with a BOM, so it should be fine. Is it possible that the tool uses an old version of Xerces which *didn't* cope with a BOM? Other than that, the file looks fine to me.

Is this a tool you have the source code to? Are you able to create a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, failing to parse it? Can you try a later version of Xerces?

Comment: this is the error i get.. i guess its mostly due to the old version of parser..
XML Parse error in AddTestOld.xml. Detailed exception info is:
tdm.lib.ParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
tdm.lib.ParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at tdm.lib.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at tdm.tool.TreeDiffMerge.merge(Unknown Source)
        at tdm.tool.TreeDiffMerge.main(Unknown Source)

Comment: Ya i have the src code for this tool. i am tryin to modify it. So its basically a parsing pblm.. The tool parses only ANSI format and since i Vs creates xmls in UTF-8 the tool is unable to parse them

Comment: @hari: Why is the tool specifying the encoding at all? You should give it an `InputStream` and let Xerces figure out the encoding.

Comment: i doubt if xerces is even havin anythng to do..i guess the default parser of tool is being used and xerces files are not invoked at all..will have to chk to tht

Comment: @hari: Well, whatever API is being used for XML parsing, just give it an `InputStream` and it *should* be able to work it out from that.

Comment: these are the lines where parse is invoked.

 InputSource is = new InputSource( new java.io.InputStreamReader( new java.io.FileInputStream(file)));      //is.setEncoding("utf-8");      xr.parse(is);
...................... and its using these headers ...
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;import org.xml.sax.Attributes;import org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl;import org.xml.sax.InputSource;import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

Comment: @hari: Posting code into comments isn't really helpful. I strongly suggest that you write a short but *complete* program (a small console app) that demonstrates the problem, and edit that into your question.

Comment: Its the Byte Order Mark which is causing the pblm...Any way to ignore tht ? it processes even Utf without BOM ...

Comment: @hari: If it's not handling the BOM, it's not compliant with the XML spec. As I've said, produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of the file created using visual studio and compare it with the notepad file encoding, that must be the issue.